# Compare child arraylist and remove object of parent object

Tags: java, android

I confused, I have parent array(products), which have inside array (component) and I have the third array (filterdata), which similar to an array in the parent. I need to compare component and filter, if some duplicated, need to remove the object in products.

```
productsList = new ArrayList<>(mSortModels);
for (ProductComponentsResponse component : filterData) {
    String componentId = component.getId();
    int componentState = component.getState();
    Iterator<ProductResponse> iterator = productsList.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        ProductResponse next = iterator.next();
        for (ProductComponentsResponse productComponentsResponse: next.getProductComponents()) {
            boolean containComponent = productComponentsResponse.getId().contains(componentId);
            if (componentState == ProductComponentsResponse.FilterState.NONE) {
                continue;
            }
            if (componentState == ProductComponentsResponse.FilterState.SELECTED) {
                if (!containComponent) {

                    iterator.remove();
                    break;
                }
            } else if (componentState == ProductComponentsResponse.FilterState.UNSELECTED) {
                if (containComponent) {
                    iterator.remove();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Could you please define the problem a bit clearer. Do you get an exception?

Comment: I don't exception